# CheсkListBox Delphi ловим нажатие

Tags: delphi

Есть CheсkListBox. Мне необходимо при нажатии на одну из ячеек, найти на какую именно нажали. Использую процедуру MouseDown. Но никак не могу понять как же определить на какой элемент нажали?

Comment: У `CheсkListBox` есть метод типа `ItemAtPos` или `GetItemAtPos` как-то так, не помню точно, который принимает на вход координаты на экране и возвращает ссылку на Item, который находится по этим координатам в данный момент (если он там есть).

Comment: В дополнение к предыдущему ответу от @kot-da-vinci. Есть еще свойство `CheckListBox1.ItemIndex`, которое возвращает индекс выбранного элемента. В `MouseDown` он уже установлен в правильное значение. Для доступа к элементам - можно воспользоваться `CheckListBox1.Items[<index>]`

Comment: @androschuk Спасибо,оформи как  ответ, отмечу правильным

Comment: @RodGers Готово

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть свойство `CheckListBox1.ItemIndex`, которое возвращает индекс выбранного элемента. В `MouseDown` он уже установлен в правильное значение. Для доступа к элементам - можно воспользоваться `CheckListBox1.Items[<index>]`